# how can i rename php files by incrementing the last number?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, cmd.exe

i want to rename files like this

`one-piece-espanol-latino - copia (1).php`

`one-piece-espanol-latino - copia (2).php`

`one-piece-espanol-latino - copia (3).php`

and 274 more...

to this in a batch

`one-piece-espanol-latino-1.php`

`one-piece-espanol-latino-2.php`

`one-piece-espanol-latino-3.php`

using windows 10 cmd

or some program

---

i solved the problem using this in cmd:

`for /l %f in (1,1,800) do copy ver-one-piece-sub-espanol-episodio-1.php ver-one-piece-sub-espanol-episodio-%f.php`

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this goal? If you have written code to achieve this goal and it does not work, this community can help you. Otherwise, this community is not a free scripting service that will code something for you from scratch.

Comment: Congratulations - you just created eight hundred identical copies of the same file. I can't believe (based on your original question) that is, what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\data -Filter *.php | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination (($_.FullName -replace " - copia \(","-") -replace "\)")}
```

Loop through all the files, and change the name by removing the bits you don't want.

Comment: Downvoted because this community is not a free scripting service that will code something for others from scratch. If the original poster has code that does not work, we can then help them debug the script. But we can’t code from scratch for people who post on the site without showing at least minimal effort shown.

Comment: but i used this   for /l %f in (1,1,800) do copy ver-one-piece-sub-espanol-episodio-1.php ver-one-piece-sub-espanol-episodio-%f.php